# Android Spinner dropdown losing Items randomly during scroll up/down

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

While scrolling custom view spinner drop down its losing menu item.

I tried all the accepted suggestions available here for similar type issues, nothing worked. here is the code.

AndroidMnifest.xml

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:largeHeap="true"

SpinnerArray.xml

```
<string-array name="spinner_categories">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    .
    .
    .
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_categories2">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    .
    .
    .
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
</string-array>
```

custom_dropdown_layout.xml

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layoutDirection="inherit"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#3b7878" />
```

Fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:shimmer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".menus.Courses">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/mSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"/>

</LinearLayout>

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/MenuView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Header"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment.java

```
private Spinner mySpinner;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mAdapter;
mySpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.mSpinner);

mAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),R.array.spinner_categories, R.layout.custom_dropdown_layout);
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_dropdown_layout);
mySpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Category = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

bg_spinner.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" android:useLevel="false">
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#3b7878" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Your java code is ok. I think you have a problem with xml view. can you mention your xml full class?

Comment: @MuhaiminurRahman  In fragment.xml I have relative layout as root, inside it i have linear layout where I have spinner. Have updated the code. Please le e know which xml you want me to update

Comment: You can follow this tutorial. Besides, I do not see any problem with your code. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm